# Problem with printing values from a struct using a void function

Tags: c, struct, printf, void

I am trying to make a program that uses a struct to store the title the author and the pages of a book.Then I want it to find which one has the lowest amount of pages and then use a void function to print its details.Whenever I run the code it seems to work but it always prints the wrong values.I am not 100% familiar with structs yet and I was wondering if somebody had an answer to why this isnt working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3

struct book{
    char title[N];
    char author[N];
    int pages[N];
};

void printbook(struct book);

int main(){
    int i,thesh;
    int min;
    struct book vivlio[N];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\ndwse titlo tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%s",vivlio[i].title);
        printf("\ndwse suggrafea tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%s",vivlio[i].author);
        printf("\ndwse selides tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%d",vivlio[i].pages);
    }
    min = vivlio[0].pages;
    thesh = 0;

    for(i=1;i<3;i++){
        if(vivlio[i].pages<min){
            min = vivlio[i].pages;
            thesh = i;
        }
    }
    printbook(vivlio[thesh]);
    return 0;
}

void printbook(struct book x){
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei ton titlo: %s",x.title);
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei ton suggrafea: %s",x.author);
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei arithmo selidwn: %d",x.pages);
}
```

Comment: `char title[N];` That will only allow 2-character titles. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Why is `pages` an array?

Comment: `min = vivlio[0].pages;` Since pages is an array, you need to index it: `min = vivlio[0].pages[0]`

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` Why aren't you using `N` here?

Comment: Please provide details on the input you're providing and the result you're seeing.

Comment: You want a container of `book` but there is no such thing in your code. Use a better abstraction and you have much less work. In the code you want an array of `book` but instead defined `book`  as a group of arrays of `char[N]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` and `author` need to be longer than 3 character, which only allows room for 2 characters plus the null terminator. `N` is the number of books, it shouldn't also be used as the number of characters.

`pages` should just be a single integer, not an array. Then when you're reading it with `scanf()`, you need to pass the address of the integer with `&`.

You should use `N` as the limit in your `for` loops, rather than hard-coding `3`.

You should end your last line of output with a newline, the the next shell prompt won't be printed on the same line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3
#define MAXTITLE 20
#define MAXNAME 30

struct book{
    char title[MAXTITLE];
    char author[MAXNAME];
    int pages;
};

void printbook(struct book);

int main(){
    int i,thesh;
    int min;
    struct book vivlio[N];

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("\n\ndwse titlo tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%s",vivlio[i].title);
        printf("\ndwse suggrafea tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%s",vivlio[i].author);
        printf("\ndwse selides tou vivliou: ");
        scanf("%d",&vivlio[i].pages);
    }
    min = vivlio[0].pages;
    thesh = 0;

    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        if(vivlio[i].pages<min){
            min = vivlio[i].pages;
            thesh = i;
        }
    }
    printbook(vivlio[thesh]);
    return 0;
}

void printbook(struct book x){
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei ton titlo: %s",x.title);
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei ton suggrafea: %s",x.author);
    printf("\n\nTo vivlio me tis ligoteres selides exei arithmo selidwn: %d\n",x.pages);
}
```

You probably also shouldn't be using `%s` to read the name and title. This only extracts a single word from the input, so you won't be able to enter names and titles with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the "pages" array should be a single integer not an array, try with:

```
int pages;
```

then when you read the pages input try with:

```
scanf("%d", &vivlio[i].pages);
```

because scanf require the address of the variable in wich to store the value